# Unknown contributor in private github repo

Tags: github

I have a private repo in my github that should not be visible to others. Somehow on a lot a files (important files) a github user shows up who is listed a "contributor"

1. How can I make sure this person has no access to my files?
2. how do I know what this person contributed or "has seen"?
3. I dont remember adding this person to my private repo. How did he appear there?

Comment: Look at the git logs - the userver name and email address will be present. From the sound of it, it's probably you, using a misconfigured git client.

Comment: Is it https://github.com/web-flow, by any chance?

Comment: Did you find the reason? I also have the same issue . Some unknown person is being shown as a contributor (firstname same as mine)  to some files in  my private repository. But if i go to check the contributors in settings , this contributor is not present.